# Create database backup from within Heroku Bash

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I want to periodically archive database dumps to my own AWS account in S3 and eventually in glacier. Is there a way to dump a postgresql database to the dynos filesystem from within the dyno (from where I then can send the file to AWS)? psql and pg_dump don't seem to be available on the dyno and I don't know how to run pgbackups from within a dyno.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if your ultimate goal is to get stuff on S3, check out [PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) which will do it automatically.

Comment: Yes I know, but this will actually delete it from there after a few days, and I'd like to keep all dumps in glacier.

Comment: PGBackups is great, but it does delete everything after a month.  We also need to store regular backups to Glacier forever, so an answer to this question would be awesome.

Comment: 'scuse my ignorance, but can you use SSH to create a tunnel and do the backup over that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with now is using the pgbackups addon (which I had been using) and then daily pulling the latest backup from s3 and uploading it back up to my bucket. A PGBACKUPS_URL env variable is exposed by Heroku if this addon is enabled. The rest would go something like this:

```
    # boto and requests are required, aws access credentials are in the settings file 

    url = settings.PGBACKUPS_URL + "/latest_backup"
    dumpfile = "./db_dump"

    # get latest backup info
    r = requests.get(url)
    dump_url = r.json()["public_url"]
    dump_timestamp = r.json()["finished_at"].replace("/", "-")
    dump_name = "db_dumps/" + dump_timestamp

    # write dump to file
    r = requests.get(dump_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(dumpfile, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content():
                f.write(chunk)

    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_DB_DUMPS_BUCKET)
    key = bucket.new_key(dump_name)
    key.set_contents_from_filename(dumpfile)
```

I have yet to find out, wether a backup can be triggered somehow via the PGBACKUPS_URL.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate heroku app to do the backups, which uses the [pgbackups-archive gem](https://github.com/kjohnston/pgbackups-archive) and then set up a heroku scheduler to run the pgbackups-archive gem periodically on your DATABASE_URL (you will need to import that environment variable from your other app), as described [here](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2012/11/21/fully-automated-almost-free-backups/).

Disclaimer: this nominally requires you to use some ruby, but works in conjunction with any heroku cedar app using heroku postgres (including django apps).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ben. I was looking for a solution for Python / Django apps. I actually also received a message from Heroku support, where the claimed that they're working on a solution where you can feed pgbackups your own S3 Bucket, which would be great.

Comment: Yeah, we also use python / django for our app, but setting up another heroku app just to do the backups from our app, with the same DATABASE_URL as our app, using the method in the link, was easy cheese and the best we could find.